# AWS CodeDeploy with Autoscaling Launch Templates with Spot and On-Demand Instances mix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

It is possible to configure an autoscaling group to use Launch Template instead of Launch Configuration. I want to use it because when I configure an autoscaling group using Launch Configuration I can not set mixed instances policy (ondemand + spot instances).

I have created launch template (name 'test') with such configuration:

```
    AMI Ubuntu 16, 
    some security groups and IAM Role with EC2, AutoScaling and CodeDeploy full access 
    and all other settings in default *Not specified* state.

    Launch Template ID lt-0e1111
    Default Version Number 1
    Launch Template Name test
    Owner arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/itsp
    Version  1 (Default)
    Name  test
    Created by arn:aws:iam::179961111910:user/itsp
    Description Not specified
    Date Created February 8, 2019 at 12:47:54 AM UTC+3
    AMI ID ami-0bf1924ed30c48a6a
    Availability Zone Not specified
    Security Groups Not specified
    Instance Type t2.nano
    Key pair name itsp
    Security Group Ids sg-07e746cf0e4935b84,sg-0a45f7e6ac321614d,sg-27bf6d4b

    Advanced Details:
    Purchasing option Not specified
    Spot request type Not specified
    Spot interruption behavior Not specified
    IAM Instance Profile Not specified
    Stop - Hibernate behavior Not specified
    Monitoring Not specified
    EBS-optimized instance Not specified
    Tenancy Host ID Not specified
    RAM Disk ID Not specified
    User Data Not specified
    Elastic Inference Accelerator Not specified
    Maximum Spot price Not specified
    Spot expiry date -
    Spot block duration Not specified
    Shutdown behavior Not specified
    Termination Protection Not specified
    Placement Group Name Not specified
    Tenancy Not specified
    Tenancy Affinity Not specified
    Kernel ID Not specified
    Elastic Graphics Not specified
```

Then I am creating an AutoScaling group with that launch template. Here is my autoscaling group configuration:

```
Launch Template test
Launch Template Version 1
Launch Template Description -
Instance Types -
Spot Diversity 0
Optional On-Demand Base 0
On-Demand Percentage 0%
Desired Capacity 1 
Min 1 
Max 1
Availability Zone(s) eu-central-1a
Subnet(s) subnet-53075e38
Classic Load Balancers -
Target Groups -
Health Check Type EC2
Health Check Grace Period 300
Instance Protection - 
Termination Policies Default
Suspended Processes -
Placement Groups -
Default Cooldown 300
Enabled Metrics -
Creation Time Fri Feb 08 00:50:16 GMT+300 2019
Service-Linked Role arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
```

Such configuration appears to be set when I choose

```
*Fleet Composition - Adhere to the launch template
The launch template determines the instance type and purchase option (On-Demand or Spot).*
```

option and my lauch template configuration is described above.

So there are no spots in my autoscaling group.

Then I configure a CodeDeploy application 'Application' and DeploymentGroup 'DG_TEST' inside of it with such configuration:

```
Deployment type Blue/green
Service role ARN arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/CodeDeployRole
Deployment configuration CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce
Rollback enabled -
Environment configuration: Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups -> Name 'test'
```

---

Ok, after everything is set up I set desired instances count to 1 in my Autoscaling group and new on-demand instance spawns in my 'test' group.

I am now starting a blue-green deployment with AWS CLI command:

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name Application --s3-location bucket=codedeploybucket,key=application,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name DG_TEST
```

And I can see new autoscaling group with same lauch template appears in my green fleet.

So we just checked all our services are working as expected.

---

Now I want to tweak my autoscaling group configuration a little to mix ondemand and spot instances in it:

```
Fleet Composition - Combine purchase options and instances
Choose a mix of On-Demand Instances and Spot Instances and multiple instance types. Spot Instances are automatically launched at the lowest price available.
Instance Types:
t2.nano (1vCPUs, 0.5GiB)
t2.small (1vCPUs, 2GiB)
t2.micro (1vCPUs, 1GiB)
Maximum Spot Price - Use default (recommended)
Spot Allocation Strategy - Diversify Spot Instances across your 2 lowest priced instance types per Availability Zone
Optional On-Demand Base - Designate the first 0 instances as On-Demand
On-Demand Percentage 50% On-Demand and 50% Spot
Desired Capacity 1
Min 1
Max 1
```

I save it and try same AWS CLI command

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name Application --s3-location bucket=codedeploybucket,key=application,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name DG_TEST
```

And now I have my deployment failed with such comment:

```
The following validation error occurred: Valid requests must contain either LaunchTemplate, LaunchConfigurationName, InstanceId or MixedInstancesPolicy parameter. (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 11111114-2b2b-11e9-93b7-11111111111)
```

---

Another strange thing is that if I configure my Launch Templae to use spots only:

```
Launch Template ID lt-00dc4c187d1111159
Default Version Number   1
Launch Template Name test2
Owner
arn:aws:iam::179961111910:user/itsp
Version     1 (Default)
Name  test2
Created by  arn:aws:iam::179961111910:user/itsp
Description Not specified
Date Created    February 8, 2019 at 1:14:13 AM UTC+3
AMI ID    ami-0bf1924ed30c48a6a
Availability Zone    Not specified
Security Groups   Not specified
Instance Type    t2.micro
Key pair name    itsp
Security Group Ids    sg-0a45f7e6ac321614d,sg-07e746cf0e4935b84,sg-27bf6d4b

Advanced details
Purchasing option    spot
Spot request type    one-time
Spot interruption behavior    Not specified
IAM Instance Profile    CodeDeployRole (arn:aws:iam::1111111111:instance-profile/CodeDeployRole)
Stop - Hibernate behavior    Not specified
Monitoring    Not specified
EBS-optimized instance   Not specified
Tenancy Host ID    Not specified
RAM Disk ID    Not specified
User Data    Not specified
Elastic Inference Accelerator    Not specified
Maximum Spot price    Not specified
Spot expiry date    -
Spot block duration    Not specified
Shutdown behavior    Not specified
Termination Protection    Not specified
Placement Group Name    Not specified
Tenancy    Not specified
Tenancy Affinity    Not specified
Kernel ID    Not specified
Elastic Graphics    Not specified
```

and use that option in my autoscaling group:

```
*Fleet Composition - Adhere to the launch template
    The launch template determines the instance type and purchase option (On-Demand or Spot).*
```

Then after same deployment command I receive another error in CodeDeploy (failed deployment reason):

```
The IAM role arn:aws:iam::179966034910:role/CodeDeployRole does not give you permission to perform operations in the following AWS service: AmazonAutoScaling. Contact your AWS administrator if you need help. If you are an AWS administrator, you can grant permissions to your users or groups by creating IAM policies.
```

And that is definitely not the case because my role for CodeDeploy have full EC2, Autoscaling and CodeDeploy access.

---

Am I doing something wrong or that are bugs? How can I configure mixed autoscaling group (ondemand+spot instances) with codedeploy using launch templates? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when working with **CodeDeploy** and **LaunchTemplates**.
It looks like LaunchTemplates are still not supported by CodeDeploy.

We have to stick to **LaunchConfigurations**. They still don't support versioning, but for the most part, they are pretty much the same :/

I could't find where AWS has documented that *little* incompatibility issue when migrating LaunchConfigurations to LaunchTemplates... but could find [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=852791) more info.

Sheers!